# Is adding to a list() object slow for runtime?

Tags: r, list

I define a list() object, and add 5x5 matrices to the list.  There are 100 matrices in total.  The way I do it now is:

```
database = list()
for (i in 1:100) {
  database[[i]] = ...
}
```

I have heard that in R, it is must faster to preallocate space rather than continuously resize - in this case, is it possible to define a list of size 100 rather than continuously add to the list, as the code is doing right now?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is possible. It is described in the help file (`?list`). Please read it.

Answer (score 0):

You can preallocate a list using the `vector` function. The following snippet creates a list of length 100.

```
database <- vector('list', 100)
```

In practice, if I'm populating all elements of a list using identical, sequential logic, I haven't found much of a performance gain from preallocation.

Comment: As described in the help page.